# Excel VBA - Array

Tags: excel, vba

A pretty basic question but I can't get it to work.
I have been playing around with Arrays in Excel VBA.

I need this functionality:
I have a table in excel say area and sales,
As excel opens I want to load this table into an array in the memory (only once per session)
and use this array instead of Vlookup etc...

Can It be done?

H

Comment: `Workbook_Open` is probably the place to do it.  Post what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: I have tried Workbook_open, I got the parameter to work in the scope of the module. It dosn't work when I try to reference it from other modules. I have solved it defined a global variable in the mudules, thank you for the help H

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What your asking can definitely be done; there are a lot of places online to learn about arrays and about running code automatically on workbook open.  Check out the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: and use the databodyrange.value of the listobject (the table)  to load into the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. Suppose I want to use A1:B3 as my array:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B3")
    arr = rng.Value
End Sub

Public arr As Variant

Sub MyCode()
    Debug.Print arr(1, 1) // prints contents cell A1
End Sub
```

Notes:

- Declaring `Public arr As Variant` makes it available globally
- You can then reference `arr` anywhere in your code e.g. in `MyCode` example